# In which all scriptures Om Namah Shivaya mantra is present?

Tags: scripture, shiva, mantras

Please share the list of scriptures as well as the exact place and link of the scriptures "Om Namah Shivaya" mantra is present.

Comment: for discussing shaivism you can also participate in agama room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53977/agama-and-tantra

Comment: there are so many scriptures that it is impossible to list for the following reasons

Comment: Not a dupe. It can be too broad but not a dupe. This post can work as a canonical post about where is the mantra present. We are getting many questions lie "Is this present in Atharva Veda, Sama veda". In future, we may get puranas also. So, this should be reopened and answered by making a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

> From this also is born **the five-syllabled mantra (Namaśśivāya)**. It indicates all knowledge. The syllables “NA” etc. follow the order of the syllables “A” etc. *- Siva Purana, Vidyesvara Samhita, Adhyaya 10, Verse 21 (Siva Purana I.10.21)*

> After you become purified by your austerity he will make you his second. O auspicious one! **listen to the mantra Om hail to Siva (Om Namah Sivaya), this is the favourite mantra of Samkara**. Hara being propitiated by you by repeating this mantra within no time he shall appear to your perception. *- Kalika Purana 43.7-8*

References -

1. [Siva Purana translated by J. L. Shastry](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225555.html)
2. [Kalika Purana translated by B. N. Shastri](https://archive.org/details/QCML_the-kalika-puran-translated-in-english-by-b-n-shastri-edited-by-surendra-pratap-nag-publishers-/mode/2up)

Answer (score 1):

> **नमः शिवायेति मंत्रं सतारं विधिना तु यः ।। चतुर्विशतिलक्षं वै जपेत्साक्षात्सशंकरः ।। ४१-३० ।। पंचाक्षरी सिद्धविद्या शिव एव न संशयः
> ।। अपवित्रः पवित्रो वा जपन्निष्पातको भवेत् ।। ४१-३१ ।।**
>
> He who performs Japa of the mantra "Namah Sivaya" alongwith Omkara in
> accordance with the injunction, for two million and four hundred
> thousand times, Shall become Sankara himself.
>
> There is no doubts that the panchaksari mantra is a siddha vidya and
> is siva himself.By performing it's japa whether one is unholy or holy,
> one becomes free of sins.

**~ Narada Purana, Uttarabhaga, Ch 41**

> **वेस्मायतनलिङ्गादेः कार्य्यमेवं विशोधनम् । स्कन्दो नमः शिवायेति मन्त्रः सर्व्वार्थसाधकः ।। ३२७.७ ।। गीतः पञ्चाक्षरो वेदे लोके गीतः
> षड़क्षरः । ओमित्यन्ते स्थितः शम्भुर्म्मुद्रार्थं वटवीजवत् ।। ३२७.८ ।।
> क्रमान्नमः शिवायेति ईशानाद्यानि वै विदुः । षड़क्षरस्य सूत्रस्य
> भाष्यद्विद्याकदम्बकं ।। ३२७.९ ।। यदोँनमः शिवायेति एतावत् परमं पदम् ।
> अनेन पूजयेल्लिङ्गं लिङ्गे यस्मात् स्थितः शिवः ।। ३२७.१० ।।**
>
> **O Skanda! The formula ‘Namah Sivaya’ is capable of accomplishing all
> things. These five syllables(Panchaakshara) are commended in the
> Vedas.** The six syllables(Shadakshara) are commended in the world. Lord
> Śambhu (Śiva) is present at the end of ‘Oṃ’ like the seed of a (holy)
> fig tree as a seal. It is known that ‘Obeisance to Śiva’ is the
> designation of Īśāna and others in order. One would acquire the
> collection of formulae by repeating the six syllables(Shadakshara).
> **‘Oṃ Namah Sivaya’ is the excellent formula.**

**~ Agni Purana, Chapter 327**

> **मन्त्रेण रुद्रागायत्र्या प्रणवेनाथ वा पुनः । ईशानेनाथ वा रुद्रैस्त्र्यम्बकेन समाहितः ।। १८.९७ पुष्पैः पत्रैरथाद्भिर्वा
> चन्दनाद्यैर्महेश्वरम् । उक्त्वा नमः शिवायेति मन्त्रेणानेन वा जपेत् ।।
> १८.९६**
>
> Lord Siva should be adored with a concentrated mind by reciting Rudra
> gayatri, Pranava, Satarudriya, Isana, and the Trayambaka or Rudra
> mantras. The flowers, leaves or water mixed with sandal paste should
> be offered to mahadeva **reciting the mantra Om Namah Sivaya**

**~ Kurma purana II.18.96**

> भवपाशनिबद्धानां देहिनां हितकाम्यया ॥आहोंनमः शिवायेति मंत्रमाद्यं शिवः
> स्वयम् ॥ १५॥ किं तस्य बहुभिर्मंत्रैः किं तीर्थैः किं तपोऽध्वरैः
> ॥यस्योंनमः शिवायेति मंत्रो हृदयगोचरः॥ १६ ॥ तावद्भ्रमंति संसारे दारुणे
> दुःखसंकुले ॥यावन्नोच्चारयंतीमं मंत्रं देहभृतः सकृत् ॥ १७ ॥
> मंत्राधिराजराजोऽयं सर्ववेदांतशेखरः ॥सर्वज्ञाननिधानं च सोऽयं चैव
> षडक्षरः ॥ १८ ॥ कैवल्यमार्गदीपोऽयमविद्यासिंधुवाडवः ॥महापातकदावाग्निः
> सोऽयं मंत्रः षडक्षरः ! ॥ १९ ॥
>
> **With a desire for the welfare of all embodied ones fettered by the
> noose of worldly existence, Śiva himself uttered the primordial Mantra
> oṃ namaḥ śivāya.**
>
> **If the Mantra oṃ namaḥ śivāya is fixed in the heart, of what avail are
> many other Mantras, many of the holy places, penances and sacrifices
> to him?**
>
> As long as embodied beings do not utter this Mantra even once, so
> long do they move round and round in the terrible mundane world
> infested with miseries.
>
> **This six-syllabled Mantra is the supreme king of the kings of all the
> Mantras, the crest-jewel of all the Vedāntas, the storehouse of all
> spiritual knowledge.**
>
> This Mantra of six-syllables is the illuminating lamp on the path of
> Kaivalya, the submarine-fire unto the ocean of ignorance, the
> forest-fire of great woods of heinous sins.

~ **Skanda purana, Brahma Khanda, Brahmottara khanda Chapter 1**

> **अथवा देवमीशानं लिंगे संपूजयेच्छिवम्।। ब्राह्मणः शिवभक्तश्च शिवध्यानपरायणः।। २६.१ ।। अग्निरित्यादिना भस्म गृहीत्वा
> ह्यग्निहोत्रजम्।। उद्धूलयेद्धि सर्वांगमापादतलमस्तकम्।। २६.२ ।।
> आचामेद्ब्रह्मतीर्थेन ब्रह्मसूत्री ह्युदङ्मुखः।। अथोंनमः शिवायेति तनुं
> कृत्वात्मनः पुनः।। २६.३ ।।**
>
> The devotee shall worship lord Śiva, Īśāna in the Liṅga, the devotee
> who is a brahmin, has faith on Śiva and. is engrossed in the
> meditation on Śiva.
>
> He shall take Bhasman originating from the Agnihotra fire repeating
> the mantra beginning with “Agni” etc. and dust it all over his body
> from head to foot.
>
> He shall wear the sacred thread, sit facing the north and perform the
> rite of Ācamana with the sacred water of the Brahman. **Repeating “Oṃ
> namaḥ Śivāya” he shall then inspire his own body.**

~ **Linga Purana II.26**

> **त्रिनेत्रं त्रिगुणाधारं त्रयाणां जनकं प्रभुम् । स्मरन्नमः शिवायेति ललाटे तत्त्रिपुण्ड्रकम् ॥ २९॥**
>
> Having taken the sacred ash and cleaned it with (the utterance of) Om,
> he should, recollecting (Śiva) the three-eyed one, the support of the
> three qualities, the creator of the three (Vedas) and the mighty one,
> with the hymn Namaḥ Śivāya, put the mark consisting of three lines
> (Tripundra) on his forehead.

~ **Brhajjabalopanishad 4th Brahmana**

The Above verse is repeated in Padma purana patala khanda Chapter 108

> **ॐ नमः शिवायेति याजुषमन्त्रोपासको रुद्रत्वं प्राप्नोति ।कल्याणं प्राप्नोति । य एवं वेद ।**
>
> One who worships with the mantra of the Yajurveda, 'Om namah Sivaya'
> attains Rudratva and achieves blessedness.

~ **Tripura Tapini Upanishad IV-12**